# Does the Linux traffic control utility modify datagrams, IP packets, or frames?

Tags: networking, kernel, traffic-shaping

I am using the Linux's traffic control (`tc`) utility, which to my understanding is used to configure the Linux kernel packet scheduler. 
I am also using the `netem` command in `tc` to add delay, drop, or corrupt traffic.

My main question is, does the `netem` modify transport layer datagrams, IP packets, or Link layer frames (like Ethernet)?

I found [this page](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/kernel_flow) which explains the network communication flow in the Linux kernel. It mentions that the shaping and queuing disciplines are made in the "Layer 2: Link layer (e.g. Ethernet)". Does this mean that `netem` adds its corruption, loss, or delay on frames (layer 2)?

But since `tc filter` allows you to apply traffic rules to a certain IP:port pair, does that mean it operates on the transport layer datagrams (layer 4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tc` affects the queuing discipline, i.e. the order in which outgoing "packets" are sent to the hardware. The implementation operates on `sk_buff` structs, and
the documentation for [sk_buff](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/sk_buff) seems to imply that the packet format is whatever the particular network interfaces uses (e.g. Ethernet packets for an Ethernet interface).

So I'd assume `netem corrupt` adds corruption on this layer, which should be discovered through the layer-2 checksum (whatever layer 2 is for a particular interface).

In addition, `sk_buff` contains pointers to the higher layer payloads, which explains why `tc filter` can act on them.